# 10k controls missing?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

I just barely crossed the 10K line on so.com. I have the tools link, but no new capabilities on any of the individual questions or answers. Does activation of these things lag? More likely, have I misunderstood the distinction between diamond and 10k, and I'm not in the business of single-handedly eliminating spam posts?

Comment: Congratulations on reaching 10k! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you aren't.

10k's must vote to close like everyone else. The only new ability you get is after 2 days of being closed, you can vote to delete a question. After 3 votes to delete, it is deleted.

The advantages of being a 10k+ user are more in the information you get. You can see all flagged posts, new tags created, lowest/highest voted questions/answers, etc. Some people use this data for different reasons.

Some people will sit on the new tags page and edit away useless tags people create such as 'coding' or 'code'.
Others will use it as a dashboard, as it tells you the most viewed/highest voted questions, you can quickly see interesting questions, and spend your time reading those instead of looking at the front page.

You also have this view that shows you new questions by new users, which you can browse and welcome our new victims... I mean customers.

Explore the tools, enjoy them.

---

And just so you don't feel too let down, several people have suggested that the 10k user's close vote count for more than 1 vote. Given to get to 10k, you have to spend a good bit of time on the site, you should be able to make more informed decisions about closing, and thus should be given more weight.

However, this option has not been implemented. I'm not sure if Jeff has even responded to it.

Comment: aw, you win.  ;-)

Comment: @Pollyanna I am .. how do you put it.... verbose. And quick :P

Comment: Gotcha. I saw the 'flagged' list and thought I'd try to be useful and swat some flagged flies.

Comment: @bmar I love being the last flag vote on a user with more than 100 rep. It is like the ultimate downvote because they loose 100 rep from my clicking.

Comment: yeah, I just lvl-uped over 10k, and feel a bit disappointed. :-'

Comment: @Chacha102 that thought occurred to me later. I'm cracking my knuckles in anticipation.

Comment: Actually, there is a new 10k ability having to do with tagging of questions while on the question page.

Comment: @Jeff I'm guessing you're either going to let us write a summary of a tag, or let us retag stuff without clicking on the edit button.

Comment: @cha it's already deployed -- mouse over the tags on a question, and move a little to the right.

Comment: @Jeff MUHUHAHAHAHAHAHA!

Comment: @Jeff this is going to make it so much less annoying to clean up tags. I just go to New Tags Page -> Click a Tag -> Click a Question -> Edit Tags -> Hit Back. Before I had to click back like 3 times to get back to the Questions page.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Chacha's answer, you can now see all deleted posts (Questions and Answers but not comments).